# display text on the same line

Tags: html, genesis-theme-framework

No matter what I do (stripping html tags or not) the following statement displays the result on 2 lines rather than one:

```
$text = sprintf( '<p>%1$s %2$s</p>', wp_filter_nohtml_kses( the_author_meta('user_firstname') ), __( 'hasn\'t published any articles yet.', 'monochrome-pro' ) );
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code here, so without being able to see the actual output on a real page, it's impossible to say. Also, `wp_filter_nohtml_kses()` is probably overkill for this. kses functions can be slow and are better used for saving to the database. For output `esc_html()` should suffice.

Comment: html outputs: `Dana <div class="entry"><p>hasn't published any articles yet.</p></div>` It keeps injecting a div for some reason.

Comment: It is a Genesis child theme if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `the_author_meta()` doesn't *return* the meta value, but *echoes* it. That's why the name is suddenly outside the `<p>` element.

Use `get_the_author_meta()` if you need to return (and do something with) the field, rather than just display it.

I'd highly recommend you to change your use usage of `__()` too, because that is not useful for translators as it's missing the name as context.

```
/* translators: %s: user's first name */
$text = sprintf(
  __( "%s hasn't published any articles yet.", 'monochrome-pro' ),
  esc_html( get_the_author_meta( 'user_firstname' ) )
);

echo '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
```

Note: if you don't trust your translations, you should use `esc_html()` on `$text` instead of the user meta. As mentioned in the comments, using KSES functions is a bit overkill. If you want to get rid of any HTML tags (vs. just escaping them) I'd use `wp_strip_all_tags()`.